# Can anybody with sufficient authority migrate this question?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration

I've flagged https://stackoverflow.com/q/7632378 twice for migration to http://codereview.stackexchange.com now. Unfortunately, it has been merely closed, but not migrated. Could anybody with sufficient reputation please migrate the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have migrated the question. Michael Mrozek is correct that we don't migrate things outside of the normal migration path unless there's a compelling reason to do so, especially to a beta site. If the beta doesn't make it, that content just kind of .. dies. Sure, it's available in a dump if that happens, but it's not on an actively served page where it could be of use to anyone. Additionally, we would not do a special migration for a question of low or mediocre quality as doing so would just create noise for the sister site.

However, I agree that CR would be a better home for the question. It seems perfectly on topic, it's rather well written, answerable and (despite being off topic for SO) it received positive attention from the community. The tags used on the question also existed on the target site.

Note, I cleaned up the comments (as they were just about getting the question over to the other site).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! I was a bit worried questioner might perhaps get a bit discouraged otherwise. It's a worthy question, and that would have been a shame.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody has enough rep for that -- there's no migration path from SO to Code Review, so only mods can migrate there. Flagging for mod attention was the right move. If you check your [flag weight summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/165154) you can see if the flags have been acted on yet; they might just be stuck in the queue. If the flags were declined it might be because they're reluctant to migrate since CR is still in beta; mods are generally discouraged from migrating to beta sites

Comment: First flag was considered helpful, second is still in queue. Should I just advise the questioner to simply copy the question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com then (since it's taking so long, and the outcome of moderation action is uncertain anyway)?

Comment: @fireeyedboy If the second flag gets dismissed and it's still not moved then that's probably a good idea; I'd wait for that though, in case a mod does decide to migrate it this time. They really should just move it, there's no reason not to if it's already closed on SO

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback Michael.